# How do I type a React input toggle value properly, what is returned via `onClick`

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

How can I type a React checkbox's return value to give the exact Union type what it can be. So if I reuse the Radio component in the Main component, and define the expected attribute type in its `onChange` method, how should I type the the `onClick` in the `RadioProps`.

In the Main component I want only the union types `CheckedType` to be passed to the onChange method, so the Radio button should be flexible with its value type and must know somehow that, always the value was passed to its `onClick` prop.

Flow complains like `...Either  string [1] is incompatible with  string literal 'Porsche'. Or ...`

```js
type CheckedType = 'Porsche' | 'Ferrari' | 'Tesla';

class Main extends React.Component {
   onChange = (checked: CheckedType) {
      ...
   }

   render() {
      return (
         <RadioGroup onChange={this.onChange}>
            <Radio ... value="Porsche" />
            <Radio ... value="Ferrari" />
            <Radio ... value="Tesla" />
         </RadioGroup>
      )
   }
}
```

```js
type RadioGroupProps = {
   ...,
   onChange: string => void
}

const RadioGroup = (props: RadioGroupProps) => {
   return (
      <div>
         {children.maps(radio => {
            return React.cloneElement(radio, {
               ...,
               onClick: props.onChange
            });
         })}
      </div>
   )
}
```

```js
type RadioProps = {
   ...,
   onClick: string => void,
   value: string
}

const Radio = (props: RadioProps) => {
   <div>
      <input type="radio" onClick={() => props.onClick(props.value)}
      ...
   </div>
}
```

Comment: But neither `onClick` nor `onChange` should return value. Meaning of question isn't quite obvious for me.

Comment: @DzhakharUkhaev updated the RadioGroup component. I hope it is more obvious now.

Comment: Is it strict requirement that RadioGroup takes Radio components as children? Is it ok to refactor the code to use an array of strings as a value of the group and to move render of Radio inside RadioGroup?